# Chaining waterline calls with Promises

Tags: orm, promise, sails.js, q, waterline

I have been hitting my head off a wall on this for the last 3 days.

I am using sailsjs & the waterline ORM that comes bundled. I want to run DB calls one after an other. I know I can do this by nesting inside "then" calls but it just looks wrong.

I have gone over the Q documentation and tutorials several times but I still don't get how to connect and fire "then" calls from existing Promises sequentially :(

I want to:

1. create a user
2. create a action
3. link the user & action
4. update the user
5. update the action

My code looks like

```
 var mail = 'test@test.com';

 Users.create({email:mail, name:''}).then(console.log).fail(console.log);

 Actions.create({actionID:123})
 .then(function(error, action){
        Users.findOneByEmail(mail).then(function(person){
            person.actions.add(action.id);
            person.save(console.log);
        }).fail(console.log)  
     });

 Users.update({email:mail},{name:'Brian'}).exec(console.log);
 Actions.update({actionID:123},{now:'running'}).exec(console.log);
```

As you can see from the code I've been using a mix of exec & then :P

I think the way is to connect the 
Users.create(...).then ->  Action.create(...).then -> Users.findOneByEmail(...).then -> *and the updates.

**Huge thanks** from any help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So after a day's research. I think I've cracked it.

**Note:** The first version I got working had the "then"s lined-up(removing the *pyramid of doom*) by returning the create. This allow me to call then on the next line to fire the create. http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial/chaining

**Here's my final version**

```
var mail = 'test@test.com';    

Users.Create({email:mail,name:''})
  .then(function(user){
    return [Actions.create({actionID:123}),user];
  }).spread(function(action, user){

     user.action.add(action.id);
     user.name = 'Brian';
     user.save();

     action.now = 'running';
     action.save();
  }).catch(console.error);
```

One of the cool things is the "spread" that allows you to line-up "Promises" and "values" to be return one they all have completed into the next "then".

Comment: Your `fail` won't work and prefer `catch`. Other than that good work!

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum
I didn't know if I needed a final done() or then() e.g.`}).then().fail(`. Would this have worked?
OR swapping the fail(...) for a catch(...) is what you mean?

Comment: Also on http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial the 1st example has `catch(...).done();` Why do we need the final **done** ?

Comment: You don't need the `done` With Bluebird promises. It is an artifact of the older Q library.

Comment: Good solution, nice use of `.spread()`. I would also return the promises which are returned from `user.save()` and `action.save()` just incase anyone wants to chain off of this operation later. so `return [user.save(), action.save()]`