# Sailsjs find() callback action

Tags: node.js, sails.js

i have a problem with my callbacks, i dont know how i get it back.

```
index: function(req, res,next) {
    User.find().exec(function(err,users) {
        if(err) {
         //do something
        }
        res.locals.users = users
        return true;
    });

   Country.find().exec(function(err,countrys) {
    //save country
   }

  console.log(res.locals.users)
  res.view({
     users: res.locals.users,
     country: countrys
     user:res.locals.user
  });
}
```

How can i get access to both objects?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your DB calls are running `async`, that means the view is rendered before the data can be passed to them. So you have to make them in synchronous manner. This can be achived via callback or you can chain your functions instead of callbacks, like this,

```
index: function(req, res,next) {
   User.find().exec(function(err,users) {
    if(err) {
     //do something
    }
    else{
      res.locals.users = users
      Country.find().exec(function(err,countrys) {
       if(err) {
           //do something
       }
       else{
           console.log(res.locals.users)
           res.view({
             users: res.locals.users,
             country: countrys
             user:res.locals.user
           });
       }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Other way is to use callbacks.

Comment: Thanks,

but if i more than 2 dbs calls , it get if else if else if else , this is not clean for me?

its not possible to return it ?

Comment: But if i want more than 2 db calls 

User.find() ... {  else Country.find().. { else Home.find()... { else Pet.find() }}}} 

this is not beautiful. 

is this the only way or can i map something or make extra function to get the data?

Comment: nest it further as i've nested `Country` under `User`... and why do you want to call same db 2 times?

Answer (score 2):

If your trying to make it pretty and organised when you keep adding more queries you can use the async library that comes with sails

see this answer as an example

[Chaining waterline calls with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438160/chaining-waterline-calls-with-promises/26442552#26442552)