# How would "this" behave normally within nested async module functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js framework and its great Model's feature, also I'm using the `async` version it uses as its dependency.

So, in order of explaining a practical scenario: *get all comments on songs sung by an artist*. I should first query the songs and then, query against comments.

This why I'm using `async` module, in particular its `waterfall` function. But as all this code is placed at a Model file, where `this` refers to the model itself, I got one big doubt:

**Will this always refer to the model even when present inside async functions?**

This is a code example of what I'm doing:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'seasonDB',
  attributes: {

    reachesMaxFavoriteTeam: function (team) {

      var results [];

      async.waterfall([

          // Get favorite team
          function (cb) {
              var userTeam = this.userTeam;

              UserTeam.findOne({_id: userTeam}, function (err, foundUserTeam) {
                  if (err)
                      cb(err,null);
                  var user = foundUserTeam.user;
                  User.find({_id: user}, {_id:false, fanOf: true}, function (err, fanOf) {
                      if (err)
                          cb(err,null);
                      cb(null,fanOf.name);
                  });
              });
          },
          // Check if it reaches a max favorite team error
          function (favoriteTeam,cb) {

              // If player to be added is from favorite team, it counts.
              favoriteCount = team === favoriteTeam ? 1: 0;

              // Check if any of added players are from favorite team too.
              _.forEach(this.players, function (player) {

                  var playerTeam = player.team.name;

                  if (playerTeam === favoriteTeam)
                      favoriteCount++;
              });


              return favoriteCount > process.env.CONDITION;
          }]);
    }
};
```

So, for example, at the first function in waterfall series I got: `var userTeam = this.userTeam;`, will this work as expected? Should I take care of something in case of other nested functions?

Comment: You could simply execute the code to see whether `this` has the correct value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use Promises in those queries will make it so much easier to work with. I wouldn't use async, using Promises should do the job.

The underlying ORM module in Sails is Waterline. You can refer to [Chaining waterline calls with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438160/chaining-waterline-calls-with-promises) for an example or the GitHub page https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline which shows the below example,

```
User.findOne()
.where({ id: 2 })
.then(function(user){
    var comments = Comment.find({userId: user.id}).then(function(comments){
        return comments;
    });
   return [user.id, user.friendsList, comments];
}).spread(function(userId, friendsList, comments){
// Promises are awesome!
}).catch(function(err){
// An error occurred
})
```

Waterline-docs is also helpful for reference: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs

Comment: What exactly is spread used for?

Comment: spread is used when array of promises are being returned. If you look at the return before .spread, the code is returning an array of values/promises.

Comment: What about "this", if it was necesary, would it be safe to use it?

Comment: Found this: http://howtonode.org/what-is-this, which looks like a pretty good read, I am reading myself. You can just declare a variable outside the chain of User.findOne and use it inside the chain if that is what you want to do. Otherwise, what are you trying to do with 'this'?